# How do I flip upside down fonts in FTGL

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, coordinates

I just use [FTGL](http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/) to use it in my app. I want to use the version `FTBufferFont` to render font but it renders in the wrong way. The font(texture?buffer?) is flipped in the wrong axis.

[image]

I want to use this kind of orthographic settings:

```
void enable2D(int w, int h)
{
    winWidth = w;
    winHeight = h;

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //I don't even want to swap the 3rd and 4th param
    //because I like to retain the top-left as the origin
    glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, 0, +1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

I render the font like this:

```
//No pushing and popping of matrices
//No translation

font.Render("Hello World!", -1, position, spacing, FTGL::RenderMode::RENDER_FRONT);
```

On the other forums, they said, just scaled it down to -1, but it wont work in mine. Example:

[image]

*font is above the screen*

I can't see relevant problem like in mine in google so I decide to ask this here again.

How can I invert texture's v-coordinate without modifying its source code ? *(assume its read only)*

Comment: "*without modifying its source code*" -- the source code of what; your program? How do you expect to fix the problem then?

Comment: @Anko the source code of FTGL. By inverting the texture v-coordinate.

Comment: Cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111457/how-do-i-flip-upside-down-fonts-in-ftgl

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with FTGL, but after some Googling I found this: http://devcry.heiho.net/2012/01/opengl-font-rendering-with-ftgl.html?m=1

Basicaly when using `glOrtho` with the rendering,  you should set the origin to the lower left corner. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man but, as I said in my post, I like the top-left corner of the window to be the origin.

Comment: Then switch it just temporarily when you draw the text and then return to the topleft origin.

Comment: Its not a good practice. Anyway, I just solved [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123725/properly-position-y-axis-of-font-in-ftgl)

Comment: @mr5 Please do write an answer with a quick summary describing how the problem was solved.

Comment: @da4c30ff Its on the link, or if unnoticeable, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123725/properly-position-y-axis-of-font-in-ftgl)